# Best practice regarding code for email addresses and downloading files from a website

Tags: php, jquery, html

This is very much a beginner's question ... I need to provide a simple website that will include a page that will allow the visitor to download some Word files. The page will also feature some email addresses. 
From a security point of view, what would be the best scripting approach or coding to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like a static HTML website, so no security issues there. That said, you might want to render the email addresses using entities or JavaScript, to ward off spambots.

Answer (score 1):

Try google feedburner. Its allow you to valid download verification
When someone subscribe on your website using feedburner then download will be possible.
The feedburner subscription is refresh in every 10 hour.

http://feedburner.google.com/

Answer (score 1):

Simple page or not, it's always good to have at least some basic security in place. As for the emails, one of the options is to keep emails stored as javascript arrays and "build" them when they need to be shown.

Example HTML:

```
<button id="one">Show first email</button>
<button id="two">Show second email</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Example implementation with comments: http://jsfiddle.net/vd4Qk/

As for the files to be downloaded, no big threat here. It's download, so a one-way process. If you ever need an upload, well, here's more to talk about.